# I am trying to get the value of a textbox in jsp using javascript.But i am unable to get.please give me some suggestion how to get it

Tags: javascript, jsp

> /*I am trying to get the value of a textbox in jsp using javascript.But i am unable to   get.please give me some suggestion how to get it.*/

```
<body>
<div class="container" id="q">
<section class="register" id="q1">

  <h1>Register Book</h1>
  <form name="BookRegistrationForm" action="./BookRegistrationController" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
  <div class="reg_section personal_info">
  <h3> BOOK TITLE :</h3><input type="text" name="bookTitle" id="bookTitle" value="">


/*to get the value i am writing this function.*/


<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
var bookTitle=BookRegistrationForm.bookTitle.value;
alert(booktitle);}
```

Comment: var bookTitle = document.getElementById("bookTitle").value

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `document` keyword to your script if you are trying to get the value from dom,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
var bookTitle=document.forms["BookRegistrationForm"]["bookTitle"].value;
alert(booktitle);
}
</script>
```

You can also do like this,

```
var bookTitle= document.getElementById("bookTitle").value;
```

**Note:**

`document.forms` will return a collection of all of the forms within a particular page.
`document.forms["BookRegistrationForm"]` will return the form with the name "**BookRegistrationForm**" from that collection , so you will be accessing the field from the mentioned form .

Hope this helps

Comment: Are you able to reference a form like that? I've never seen that.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
document.getElementById("bookTitle").value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `document.getElementById()`;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate(){
        var bookTitle = document.getElementById("bookTitle").value;
        alert(booktitle);
    }
</script>
```